# What do you advise to show data on computer via a serial port

Tags: user-interface, serial-port, acquisition

I have a device. When I connect it to my PC Using a serial port, I can see data on hyper terminal.

I know what to send from the meter to get on the hyper terminal as:

TX = Voltage_Phase_A while the serial port communication is stable!

Now, here is my question.

I do not want to use any terminal. I would like to have my own version of terminal. Just a simple window that grabs the data out of my device and show it on PC.

So, what language you would think that is straightforward and easy to use and what IDE I should use to make such GUI? Is this project east to do? Any examples that I can have?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What will your solution accomplish that hyperterminal or putty will not?

Comment: Reason: I would like to have that piece of data and analyse it later on. In other words, subtract from a special amount and show it on the other window later on.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a separate c++ app that listens to that serial port in a loop. Writing a serial listener in c++ is not that straight forward, you also can do it in c#:
Here is a sample app that does this in c#:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/75770/Basic-serial-port-listening-application

Comment: Which one is easier to learn and understand and quick to apply? C# or C++? I guess C# as you mentioned right?

Comment: BTW, the program that you have sent to me is not functioning when I set the port and push "start to listen"!